# How to find the smallest number in a factorial Java

Tags: java, windows, factorial

I don't know how to find the smallest factorial number in
java, I searched online on what to do but nothing helped.
it says to do something like this but i don't understand it:

> 120/1 = 120  =>  120/2 = 60  =>  60/3 = 20  =>  20/4 = 5  =>  5/5 = 0
> In this case, our number "5"

heres my code:

```
public class {
        public static void main(String[] args){
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           long i, fact = 1;
           long n = scan.nextLong();
           for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
             fact = fact*i;

         }
         System.out.println(fact);

      }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the smallest factorial number"?

Comment: heres an example: 120/1 = 120  =>  120/2 = 60  =>  60/3 = 20  =>  20/4 = 5  =>  5/5 = 0
In this case, our number "5"

Comment: You want to find the smallest *prime factor*, not the smallest *factorial*.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are each a positive integer, how do you test if `a` is a factor of `b`? One way is to use the `%` operator:   `if ( b % a == 0) { System.out.println ("a is a factor of b");`. Note that `a` is not necessarily a *prime* factor.

Comment: 5/5 = 1 not zero

Comment: But it's not the smallest prime factor either, as the smallest prime factor of 120 is 2. But also, the example is wrong anyway, since it has `5/5 = 0` in it. So, IDK what is going on or what this question is supposed to mean

Comment: @potatocode0 - Your single example is not sufficient to understand what you are asking for.  What would the answer be for n == 64 or n == 31 or n == 100?

Comment: Are you looking for the inverse of the factorial function? i.e., If x! = y, given y, find x.

Comment: I think @OldDogProgrammer is correct; in which case, most numbers are not factorial numbers. Just multiply 1 x 2 x 3...  and if you hit the target number exactly, the last multiplier is your answer.  If you pass the target number, there is no answer satisfying the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear, the question says "Find the smallest factorial" the smallest factorial of any number is always 1.

However in your test case, it looks like you are trying to find out the greatest factorial. (although 5/5 = 1 and not 0).

Here's code to find the greatest factorial in given range(n):

```java
public class class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        long i, fact = 120, lastFact=1;
        long n = scan.nextLong();
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if(fact%i == 0){
                fact /= i;
                lastFact = i;
            }
            if(fact < 2){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lastFact);
    }
}
```

Comment: ['Factor'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) and ['factorial'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) have very different meanings.  You mean 'factor'.  Maybe the OP meant that too.

Comment: @undefinedsymbol maybe I misunderstood the question but, there are only 2 possibilities, as per his example, this is one possibility, but if he want to find the smallest factorial in given range, but which does not make sense as the value for factorial of each natural number is unique, say 5! does not equal to 6!

Comment: This code does calculate the result of a factorial inverse function. But, `120` shouldn't be hardcoded.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer from the code that OP provided, it seems that he's taking only 1 input, i.e. the maximum range of the number, however if he wants to take user input for the number as well, just replace `fact = 120` with `fact = scan.nextLong()`